# Javascript Timestamp Logic

Tags: javascript, function, variables, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Hi I want to track “the time it takes a user to complete a purchase from a defined starting event” with the `_trackTiming` method in Google Analytics.

**Method suggested by** [this blogpost](https://www.e-nor.com/blog/google-analytics/time-on-site-2-0-tracking-conversion-duration-in-google-analytics):

1. Create a timestamp at the defined starting point. (Done)
2. Save the timestamp in a cookie. (I have a cookie in `{{conversionDurationCookie}}` )
3. Create a timestamp at the end of the conversion.
4. Calculate the time duration from start to the purchase.
5. Fire the `_trackTiming` method to track the duration in GA.
6. Once this data is collected I will see the data in Content > Site Speed > User Timings in Google analytics.

**Code 1-2**

```
//this is fired at the defined starting point
var cookieName    = conversionDurationCookie;
var cookieValue   = new Date().getTime();
var cookieExpires = 1000 * 60 * 30;
document.cookie   = cookieName + '=' + cookieValue + '; Expires=' + cookieExpires;
```

**Code 3-5:**

```
// this is fired at the conversion
t2 = new Date().getTime();
conversionDuration = (t2 – {{conversionDurationCookie}})
ga("send", "timing", ["conversionDuration"], ["conversionDuration"], ["conversionDuration"]);
```

**Code 3-5 (version 2):**

```
// this is fired at the conversion
var t2 = new Date().getTime();
function conversionDuration(t2 – {{conversionDurationCookie}}) {
ga("send", "timing", ["conversionDuration"], ["conversionDuration"], ["conversionDuration"]);
}
```

**Question 1-6**

Before I do #6 do the logic look correct? Code 3-5 (version 2)? Correct format on functions and variables?

Best
//H

Comment: Are you sure that you use "classic" Analytics (which has been deprecated for at least two years) ? If you use the current GA version (Universal Analytics)  you'd need to convert your syntax to ga('send','timing'...).

Comment: @EikePierstorff changed! anything else you notice?